# SceneKit object from function does not appear in Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scenekit

Hello I am trying to run two examples on Xcode. The first is apple's demobots example  and the other is coin push example I found on GitHub. Both times I get the same single error, 'Method does not override any method from its superclass' and I am stuck on the best way to correct these.

These are the respective lines of code

1.

```
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {

        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
    }

    else {

        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
         }
    }
```

2.

```
 override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String: AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    // Check if this is the KVO notification we need.

    if context == &progressSceneKVOContext && keyPath == "fractionCompleted" && object === progress {

        // Update the progress UI on the main queue.

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            guard let progress = self.progress else { return }

            // Update the progress bar to match the amount of progress completed.
            self.progressBarNode.size.width = self.progressBarInitialWidth * CGFloat(progress.fractionCompleted)

            // Display a contextually specific progress description.
            self.loadingLabelNode.text = progress.localizedDescription
        }
    }

    else {

        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the declarations of the classes that have the above 2 methods?

Comment: Hello @AntonBronnikov :       1.       `class GameViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate`.   2.  `    class ProgressScene: BaseScene`

Comment: Hello @AntonBronnikov :                                                                                1.       `class GameViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate`.                                                                     2.     `class ProgressScene: BaseScene`

Answer (score 0):

In case (1), base class `UIViewController` has method `supportedInterfaceOrientations` with signature `() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask` and not `() -> Int`.  This is what the error message is telling you about, that is, the method that you provide implementation for does not override any method from base class, but instead it is a new method available in sub-class only.

I think case (2) is a similar story.